# Using Django context variable in JQuery

Tags: jquery, json, django

I am stuck trying to use Django template variable in Jquery. And specifically, I can't figure out whether it's a JSON object or not?

Here's my code:

HTML:

```
{% for task in task_table %}    
    <tr task = '{{task}}' style = 'cursor:pointer'>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function () {

    $('#taskTable tr').click(function()
    {
        task_to_update =  $(this).attr('task');
        alert (task_to_update.auth_user__last_name);
```

The task_to_update looks like this (sorry for the long line):

```
"{'auth_user__last_name': u'\u041c\u043a\u0440\u0442\u0447\u044f\u043d', 'task__date_end': datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 16, 0, 0), 'auth_user_id': 4L, 'task_id': 223L, 'auth_user__first_name': u'\u0422\u0438\u0433\u0440\u0430\u043d', 'task__initiator__first_name': u'\u042d\u0434\u0433\u0430\u0440', 'task__description_short': u'\u041f\u043e\u0432\u0442\u043e\u0440\u043d\u0430\u044f \u0432\u044b\u0433\u0440\u0443\u0437\u043a\u0430 \u043f\u043e\u0441\u0442\u0430\u0432\u0449\u0438\u043a\u043e\u0432', 'task__status_id': 1L}"
```

...and here's how task is defined in Django view:

```
task_table = TaskResponsiblePeople.objects.values('task_id',
                                                       'auth_user_id',
                                                       'task__description_short',
                                                       'task__date_end',
                                                       'task__initiator__first_name',
                                                       'task__status_id',
                                                       'auth_user__first_name',
                                                       'auth_user__last_name')
```

I don't even know whether I should first parse it as a JSON or not ? JSON.parse(task_to_update) gave me error `VM5580:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 1`. I am newbie to this Django + JQuery architecture, please bear me with me and suggest any solution to this !

Comment: is task in `{{task}}` is a dictionary?

Comment: I've edited the question to include the Django view and HTML part.

Answer (score 0):

That is not valid JSON: it is a Python dict, which is not the same thing.

You haven't shown enough of your view, but you should certainly be converting it to JSON there, before you send it to the template.